# Fourier Transform of Gaussian over Gaussian (sort of)

Tags: fourier-transform

I need help with the inverse fourier transform of the following expression

$$\frac{ae^{-w^2/2}}{ae^{-w^2/2}+b}$$

where $a > 0,b > 0$ and $w$ is the angular frequency.

Top term is simply a Gaussian. It looks very simple except the additive term in denominator which complicates things.

Answer (score 2):

At least for $|a| < |b|$, you can express your function as a convergent series in powers of $a$:

$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1} \frac{a^n}{b^n} e^{-nw^2/2}$$

and then transform term-by-term.

Comment: What is this series called? Can it be applied to any function with a*f(x)/(a*f(x) + b)?

Comment: It's just a geometric series.